# Sharepoint REST API filter empty LookUp field

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-api

I'd like to know how I can filter ListItems in SharePoint rest API (2013) on empty lookup.
On my list items, there is a lookup (single value, not required) and i'd like to get all items where lookup is empty (blank).

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$select=Id&$expand=MyLookUp/Id&$filter=??
```

Does someone has a clue ?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**REST API in SharePoint 2013 does Not support null values for filtering on list item queries**.

**However you can combine CAML query with REST API to get the required data.**

Please refer below code : 
(Note : please change your query/URL):

```
 function _rest_Post(rquest) {
        return $.ajax({
            method: rquest.method,
            url: rquest.url,
            contentType: rquest.contentType,
            headers: rquest.header,
            data: JSON.stringify(rquest.body),
        });

    }

function GetByCaml(serviceParams) {
    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + serviceParams.create.lName + "')/getitems",
        header: {
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        body: serviceParams.create.body,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",

    };
    return _rest_Post(req);

}

function getData(){
    var queryViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><IsNull><FieldRef Name='Project_x0020_Manager'/></IsNull></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields></View>";
    var params = {};
    params.create= {};
    params.create.lName = "MyList";
    params.create.filter = "";
    params.create.body = {
        'query':{ 
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' },
            'ViewXml': queryViewXml
        }
    }
    return GetByCaml(params);
};


getData().then(function(data){
    //success handler
}, function(error){
    //failure handler
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found a solution that does work using REST, you simply filter the lookup ID to greater than 0. All lookup IDs are 1 or greater, but using not equal to 0 (MyLookup ne 0) fails, because null is not equal to 0. However, null is, apparently, not GREATER THAN 0, either. It might make the math geeks twitch, but it works.

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('abc')/items?$select=Id&$expand=MyLookUp/Id&$filter=MyLookup gt 0
```

Answer (score 1):

OP, your answer is really close. The Id value for empty lookups should be -1. If you explore the raw data with something like SP CAML Query Helper you should see -1;# in the unselected lookups.

/items/?$select=Id,Title,Assigned_x0020_To/Id&$expand=Assigned_x0020_To&$filter=(Assigned_x0020_To eq -1) should work for you.