# Get items from a SharePoint List using REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013

I like to retrieve data from two lists using the REST API in SP 2013.
When looking at some examples I see the mentioning of a Id field. Is that a field
which is added automatically by SP when you use a lookup field to get data from a second List?

My first list = OIE Alerts, field (lookup) "Country"
My second list = Countries, fields (text) "LandNaam" and (text) "LandCode"

for example Nederland, Nederland, NLD
There is no Id field in my lists. So could I use like this without an Id field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharepoint REST API filter empty LookUp field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959179/sharepoint-rest-api-filter-empty-lookup-field)

Answer (score 0):

The ID field is automatically added. Anytime you create a new list the first item entered into the list will have ID 1. Deleting the item will not reset the ID count. So if you have ID 1, 2, 3 and delete item 2, the next item added to the list will have ID 4.

Essentially when you create a list you are creating a table in SQL. You can go into your list via SharePoint, modify the view of your list, and ID will be an option that you can show on the list.

If you pull all the items from the list, then you will have to traverse the object to get the fields you want.

Comment: Matt,
so basically I don't need the ID object when I retrieve items from my two lists.

Comment: @Marco I don't believe so. I do SOAP requests and I just get the entire list, use a loop on the responseXML and get the columns I need by row. I'm sure your situation is essentially the same.